# How often to cite / back-up claims?

Tags: citations, paper-submission

Good morning all,

I have recently embarked on an MSc programme in CompSci, on which the first module is Critical Reading/Writing. So far, I have written two "introductory" paper assessments. As I was writing them, I found that my text read somewhat "monotonous", and I felt that not only every claim should be backed-up by a citation, but literally every instance of an assertion. For example:

> "Smith writes that all Electrofuzzies are vulnerable to extreme
> cold[1]. Jones contests Smith's recent study on thermal vulnerability
> of Electrofuzzies in [2] and finds they can tolerate up to absolute zero just fine. This paper argues that it's not enough to simply test for
> cold-resistance; one should also test for extreme heat to obtain a
> more general picture"

In the above purely-fictitious text (well, perhaps Electrofuzzies actually exist - I don't really know), the first two sentences try to illustrate what I meant by "monotonous" - just fact after fact with no eloquent linkage. The last sentence "It's not enough ...", tries to illustrate that I fear that every time I wax assertive in a paper, I need to back it up.

**Questions**

- Would this then not just turn my paper into one large symbolic link to others' work?
- How much freedom of expression should I give myself, assuming that I'm not an authoritative source on Electrofuzzies or literally anything in CompSci at the academic level?
  Should I literally cite/reference at every opportunity, if not?

Thank you for any advice!

Comment: Have you asked your instructor?  Their opinion is what matters.  Did you get instructions?

Comment: What do you mean by "every time I wax assertive"? And what by citing at any opportunity?

Comment: I do not know the details of your course, but I see no problem with your example text.

Comment: Two things bother me about your example text, but neither is what you're asking about. (1) Shouldn't "up to absolute zero" be "down to absolute zero"? (2) "This paper" could mean (and I think is intended to mean) the paper in which this example text appears, or it could mean the paper [2] that was just mentioned. I'd write either "The present paper argues" or (preferably in my view but anathema to some folks) "We argue".

Comment: @AndreasBlass - Good points. I wrote it in haste, but yes - both of your niggles hold weight; thanks!   %"henning -- reinstate Monica", I mean every time I assert something myself, or give my own opinion - or should I write papers like an academic "router", simply vectoring off to other papers? %Anonymous Physicist - You are right; I should, but they have many other students to help, and are not super responsive (I did get instructions, but my question relates not to any one assignment; rather, to a fundamental misunderstanding I believe I have). Thanks all, for your replies.